# jQuery: How to implement that kind of slider?

Tags: jquery, scroll

I want to slide through a range of images as soon as the mouse pointer reaches the middle of the first image. As soon as the mouse pointer reaches the middle of the first of the images, scrolling should slide the images up or down.

Once the last image is hit, scrolling should go back to normal and scroll the entire page down. Same for up, when the first image is hit again and the user keeps scrolling, the page should scroll up.

Example: http://www.google.de/nexus/5/ (scroll down a bit until you see the 2nd mobile phone).

Is there a jQUery plugin out there maybe? I searched, but found nothing useful. Thanks fpr your help!

Answer (score 0):

Thats called "Paralax scrolling" check this [tutorials](http://wedesignpixel.com/best-jquery-parallax-scrolling-tutorials/)